# Generic method and NRT return type - weird compiler warning

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types

I have the following generic method:

```
public static T? Foo<T> (string param1, T? param2)
    where T : class, IEnumerable
{
    // ...
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

> Error CS8627: A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type unless language version '9.0' or greater is used. Consider changing the language version or adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint.

However, as you can see, I already added the "class" constraint. So what else am I missing here?

VS 2019 16.8.1

Comment: It compiles fine for me on [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEA3GUCWAZgJ4A+AAgEwCMAsAFAMDEAdgK4A2HAhsBzAAIYLXvwYNyAZgFUBAYQEBvBgNUzp5akgEAVAPwCAYhAgAeHQD4BACk0AGAQAduUbgFtqaXQeeu3lAEoVNQB3AAs8QR0BEBlKBmV6NRkAdgF2LgBuBgBfXKA==)...

Comment: I just realized it might have to do with the old csproj format we're using.

Comment: Tangential: what changed in C# 9.0 that it is no longer required? I cannot find any info on this

Comment: @D.R. you can be right. Feature is a part of C#8 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) which is available in .NET Core 3.X and .NET Standard 2.1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). Old csproj is for .NET Framework and doesn't support C#8.